from raider import RAiDER ( RAiDER importation)
Can someone help me out in import RAiDER from raider? I've tried it several times but it's not running.
It was writing could not import RAiDER.
And can I import RAiDER from another package aside raider?
!pip install raider
from raider import RAiDER 

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[145], line 1
----> 1 from raider import RAiDER

ImportError: cannot import name 'RAiDER' from 'raider' (C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\raider\__init__.py)


Where did you get this example code from? Can you [edit] your question to include what the package is, what you're trying to do with it, and what this code is for?
